# How to get same result from js code to dart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flutter, dart

I am developing app in Flutter. I am zero for js/css/html. I just want add like or heart animation same like Instagram live strame. I found some code that is written in the js. I tried my self to convert to dart but didn't get success.

*- Please check below link of js code*

https://codesandbox.io/s/instagram-live-like-animation-forked-pfjtpz?file=/src/App.js

[image]

I want same animation like above so I tried to convert it to dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  List<int> likes = [];
  void cleanLike(int id) {
    setState(() {
      likes.removeWhere((like) => like == id);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Hello CodeSandbox"),
              Text("Start editing to see some magic happen!"),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          likes.add(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text("Like"),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: likes.map((id) {
                        return Bubble(
                          onAnimationEnd: cleanLike,
                          key: Key(id.toString()),
                          id: id,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Bubble extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  final Function onAnimationEnd;

  Bubble({Key? key, required this.id, required this.onAnimationEnd});

  @override
  _BubbleState createState() => _BubbleState();
}

class _BubbleState extends State<Bubble> {
  late double size;
  late int emoji;
  late double animationDuration;
  late GlobalKey element;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    size = random(0.7, 1.5);
    emoji = random(0, emojis.length - 1).floor();
    animationDuration = random(2, 5);
    element = GlobalKey();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: element,
      child: Text(
        emojis[emoji],
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}

double random(double min, double max) {
  return Random().nextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
}

const List<String> emojis = ["❤️", " ", "❤️", " "];
```

Anyone here who know both js and dart or know how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**output**:

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

const List<String> emojis = ["❤️", " "];

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  List<Widget> likes = [];
  int counterKey = 0;

  void removeLike(Key keyToRemove) {
    setState(() {
      likes.removeWhere((element) {
        return element.key == keyToRemove;
      });
    });
  }

  addLike() {
    final uniquKey = Key(counterKey.toString());

    // add like widget
    likes.add(
      LikeAnimation(
        key: Key(counterKey.toString()),
      ),
    );
    setState(() {});
    // remove like after 2 seconds
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    ).then((value) => removeLike(uniquKey));

    counterKey++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: likes.map((e) => e).toList()),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: addLike,
              child: const Text("Like"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LikeAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const LikeAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  State<LikeAnimation> createState() => _LikeAnimationState();
}

class _LikeAnimationState extends State<LikeAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late int emoji;

  late Animation<Offset> offsetAnimation;
  late Animation<double> fadeInAnimation;
  late AnimationController controller;

  final Duration _duration =
      Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(200) + 2000);

  Offset get begin => const Offset(0, 0);
  Offset get end {
    var y = Random().nextInt(10) - 100;
    var x = Random().nextDouble() * 50;
    x = Random().nextBool() ? x : -x;
    return Offset(x, y.toDouble());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    offsetAnimation.removeListener(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    randomEmoji();
    initializeAnimation();
  }

  randomEmoji() {
    emoji = Random().nextInt(emojis.length);
  }

  initializeAnimation() {
    controller = AnimationController(duration: _duration, vsync: this);
    fadeInAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.2).animate(controller);
    offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(begin: begin, end: end).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: offsetAnimation.value,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: fadeInAnimation,
        child: Text(
          emojis[emoji],
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 26),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for -- I which I can give 10+ upvote :)